# Rendering on specific pages through application.html.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a search box that I only want to render on particular pages through the navigation section in my application.html.erb file.

How do I set exceptions? Is this done through the main application controller?

Comment: Like what type of conditions, you want to use to show search box ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

Most obvious way is to use an instance variable for flagging.

In your `application.html.erb`

```rb
<%= render 'search' if @search_box %>
```

And wherever you want to show the search, set the flag instance variable to true.

```
def show
  @search_box = true
  ...
end
```

---

Edit

You might also want to utilize Rails' filters in your controllers if you want multiple actions to show search.

```rb
before_action :flag_search_box, :only => [:show, :new, :all_kinds_of_controller_actions_where_i_wanna_show_search]

...

private

  def flag_search_box
    @search_box = true
  end
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm rendering my search box through a partial within application.html.erb by using <%= render 'search' %>, when someone tries logging in through devise, I get an ugly error, which is fine, I only want the search box to render on particular pages.

Comment: That's ok. The idea still remains the same. You can render the search partial only for certain views with the flagging instance variable.

Comment: Yup, did I do it? Not sure, my rating is so crappy, I don't think I can rate any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest to put the search box not in the application.html page but maybe in the separate html pages that you want it to render on. You could make the search a partial so that you could access it from the other pages with just one line of code.